# How to make generator work in spark mapPartitions()?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, bigdata

I am trying to use mapPartiton in spark to process large text corpus:
Let's say we have some half-processed data that looks like this:

```
    text_1 = [['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E'],
    ['F', 'E', 'G', 'A', 'B'],
    ['D', 'E', 'H', 'A', 'B'],
    ['A', 'B', 'C', 'F', 'E'],
    ['A', 'B', 'C', 'J', 'E'],
    ['E', 'H', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
    ['E', 'G', 'A', 'B', 'C'],
    ['C', 'F', 'E', 'G', 'A'],
    ['C', 'D', 'E', 'H', 'A'],
    ['C', 'J', 'E', 'H', 'A'],
    ['H', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'F'],
    ['H', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'J'],
    ['B', 'C', 'F', 'E', 'G'],
    ['B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'H'],
    ['B', 'C', 'F', 'E', 'K'],
    ['B', 'C', 'J', 'E', 'H'],
    ['G', 'A', 'B', 'C', 'F'],
    ['J', 'E', 'H', 'A', 'B']]
```

Each letter is a word. I also have  vocabulary :

```
    V = ['D','F','G','C','J','K']
    text_1RDD = sc.parallelize(text_1)
```

and I want to run the following in spark:

```
    filtered_lists = text_1RDD.mapPartitions(partitions)

    filtered_lists.collect()
```

I have this function:

```
    def partitions(list_of_lists,vc):

            for w in vc:

                iterator = []
                for sub_list in list_of_lists:

                    if w in sub_list:
                        iterator.append(sub_list)

        yield (w,len(iterator))
```

If I run it like this:

```
    c = partitions(text_1,V)
    for item in c:
        print(item)
```

it returns correct count

```
    ('D', 4)
    ('F', 7)
    ('G', 5)
    ('C', 15)
    ('J', 5)
    ('K', 1)
```

However, I have no idea how to run it in spark:

```
    filtered_lists = text_1RDD.mapPartitions(partitions)

    filtered_lists.collect()
```

It has just one argument and generates a lot of errors when running in Spark...

But even if I code vocabulary inside partitions function:

```
    def partitionsV(list_of_lists):
            vc = ['D','F','G','C','J','K']
            for w in vc:

                iterator = []
                for sub_list in list_of_lists:

                    if w in sub_list:
                        iterator.append(sub_list)

        yield (w,len(iterator))
```

..I got this:

```
    filtered_lists = text_1RDD.mapPartitions(partitionsV)

    filtered_lists.collect()
```

output:

```
     [('D', 2),
     ('F', 0),
     ('G', 0),
     ('C', 0),
     ('J', 0),
     ('K', 0),
     ('D', 0),
     ('F', 0),
     ('G', 0),
     ('C', 0),
     ('J', 0),
     ('K', 0),
     ('D', 1),
     ('F', 0),
     ('G', 0),
     ('C', 0),
     ('J', 0),
     ('K', 0),
     ('D', 1),
     ('F', 0),
     ('G', 0),
     ('C', 0),
     ('J', 0),
     ('K', 0)]
```

Obviously, generator didn't work as expected. I am totally stuck.
I am very new to spark. I would be so grateful if someone can explain to me what is going on here...

Answer (score 0):

That's yet another word-count problem, and `mapPartitions` is not the tool for the job:

```
from operator import add

v = set(['D','F','G','C','J','K'])

result = text_1RDD.flatMap(v.intersection).map(lambda x: (x, 1)).reduceByKey(add)
```

And the result is

```
for x in result.sortByKey().collect(): 
    print(x)
```

```
('C', 15)
('D', 4)
('F', 7)
('G', 5)
('J', 5)
('K', 1)
```

Comment: I tried something like that, but the final goal is not to find out how many times each word (letter A,B,..) occurred in text_1 corpus but rather the number of UNIQUE neighbors (for example, 5-gram co-occurring words) for each word in the V.So, it looked to me I need to go by lines, not with flatMap, so I was thinking about generators.